# javascript indexOf class containing element

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, class, indexof

I have an array of elements of the same class, how can I search indexOf with only one element from the class

```
class Dhash {
  constructor(Dlable, tophash) {
    this.Dlable = Dlable;
    this.tophash = tophash;
  }
}
let listohashs = [];
listohashs[0] = new Dhash(0x001003, 0xfffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffa);
listohashs[1] = new Dhash(0x011003, 0xfffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffb);
listohashs[2] = new Dhash(0x021003, 0xfffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffc);

console.log(listohashs.indexOf(0x001003));  // <-- here be the problem
```

I need it to return 0 for this example as it matches `listohashs[0].dlable` that way i can get the corosponding `tophash` value

I have tried:
 `console.log(listohashs.indexOf(0x001003));` and putting `.dlable` anywhere in there that I could think of.

can I search with a wild card in one of the element places?
i.e. where * will match anything

```
searchohash = new Dhash(0x001003, *);
console.log(listohashs.indexOf(searchohash));
```

Is json what i should be using? im new to js and just started using json a few days ago

Comment: I think what you're looking for is [findIndex](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The indexOf() method returns the first index at which a given element
> can be found in the array, or -1 if it is not present. - MDN

You are looking for the element whose value if `0x001003` but `listohashs` is an array of objects. So you are comparing the object with `0x001003` which won't be equal so it will return `-1`.

You can use [`findindex`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex) here, You have to find the `index` of the object whose `Dlable` property value is `0x001003`

```js
class Dhash {
  constructor(Dlable, tophash) {
    this.Dlable = Dlable;
    this.tophash = tophash;
  }
}
let listohashs = [];
listohashs[0] = new Dhash(0x001003, 0xfffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffa);
listohashs[1] = new Dhash(0x011003, 0xfffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffb);
listohashs[2] = new Dhash(0x021003, 0xfffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffc);

console.log(listohashs.findIndex((o) => o.Dlable === 0x001003)); // <-- here be the problem
```

Answer (score 2):

`indexOf` only works if the argument is an actual element of the array, not just a property of it.

Use `findIndex()` to find an element using a function that will perform the appropriate comparison.

```js
class Dhash {
  constructor(Dlable, tophash) {
    this.Dlable = Dlable;
    this.tophash = tophash;
  }
}
let listohashs = [];
listohashs[0] = new Dhash(0x001003, 0xfffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffa);
listohashs[1] = new Dhash(0x011003, 0xfffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffb);
listohashs[2] = new Dhash(0x021003, 0xfffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffc);

console.log(listohashs.findIndex(h => h.Dlable == 0x001003));
```